# jQuery bind function and (this) usage

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.box').click(function () {

    $(this).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $(this).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
});
```

This code works perfectly for animating unlimited `<div class="box">` across the screen one after the other. You can click anywhere on the div to make it animate. Inside these divs are multiple choice questions and I want the animation to trigger on a next button `<button class="forward">`.

How can I put the click function in the first line on the .forward element and still retain the (this) and next() progression through the list.

Seems like I need to switch the html element to .box in line 2 (blank right now)

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/stupaul22/JwC65/5/

Comment: Instead of deleting your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048855/jquery-selector-and-this-html-element-usage) and reposting it, you could have just edited it. *edit:* Apparently you did. Why did you delete it then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Q39YX/2/

I added an `active` class to the current active question, and I use that as the selector rather than `this`.

**Edit**: I added the following:

1. put questions and buttons in separate containers to avoid having `next()` select the buttons.
2. used `:last-child` and `:first-child` selectors together with `:not` to avoid selecting the first question when the back button is clicked and the last question when the forward button is clicked.

   ```
    $('.forward').click(function() {
        $('.active:not(:last-child)').animate({
            left: '-50%'
        }, 500);
        $('.active:not(:last-child)').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active').animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    });
    $('.back').click(function() {
        $('.active:not(:first-child)').animate({
            left: '150%'
            }, 500);
        $('.active:not(:first-child)').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active').animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    });
   ```

Comment: I updated the fiddle with the Mosho's code and I added the code for the back button. 
Forward and back are working well but I am still having problems at the start and finish.
There are 11 questions. If you are on question 1 and you press the back button the div slides right and you are left with a blank screen and the buttons no longer seem to work.

Comment: What I need is for the back button to be disabled when its question 1.

Comment: Also after question 11 if you press next you get a blank screen, then if you press next again the buttons move left off the screen and the final message animates on.

Comment: What I need is when you are at question 11 and you press next the final message should come in, the buttons should not move away and the next button should now be disabled. (back should work)

Comment: @StackErr http://jsfiddle.net/stupaul22/FF9Ga/3/ I tried to use the else statement to remove the back and next buttons at the last slide. It was one loop off (requiring an extra click). I got it working with a second if statement. Would you improve the code in any way?